# Prove that an integer is a multiple of $14$ if and only if it is a multiple of $2$ and $7$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

This is actually written as an equality: 
$\{14x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{2x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \{7x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I have been advised to study this and prove it, but I am totally lost as to how to do so. A push in the right direction would be incredible. Thanks!

Comment: The best tip is to show that either set is a subset of the other. To do that, use the definition of being a multiple

Comment: Yes, $m\Bbb Z\cap n\Bbb Z=d\Bbb Z$ with $d=?$. Have a look at this site!

Comment: Another tip: An object is an element of the intersection of two sets if and only if it is in both sets. This is something you can use without any further proof.

Comment: Hint: $\ 2\mid 7x=x\!+\!6x\,\Rightarrow\,2\mid x\ \ $

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Bill, I am not familiar with this notation. What does 2 | 7x and 2 | x mean?

Comment: @rustybandit: The vertical stroke "$\mid$" in this context means that the expression to the left is a *divisor* of the expression to the right.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is straightforward. To prove

$\{14x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \{2x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \{7x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

consider a member of $n$ of $\{14x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. So we know that $n=14m$ for some integer $m$.

Then we can also say that $n=2a$ where $a=7m$ is an integer. So $n \in \{2x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

And we can say that $n=7b$ where $b=2m$ is an integer. So $n \in \{7x|x \in 
\mathbb{Z}\}$.

And putting these pieces together we have

$n \in \{14x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \implies (n \in \{2x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}) \land (n \in \{7x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}) \\ \Rightarrow \{14x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \{2x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \{7x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Going in the other direction is a little more difficult and depends on a property of $2$ and $7$ that not all pairs of integers share. To see what this might be, let's replace $2$ and $7$ with $6$ and $10$. Then we have

$\{60x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \{6x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \{10x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

and the proof is essentially the same as for $2$ and $7$. But it is not true that

$\{6x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \{10x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \{60x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} $

because $30 \in \{6x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cap \{10x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ but $30 \not \in \{60x|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

So what makes $2$ and $7$ different from $6$ and $10$ ?